# Prove a commutative ring with characteristic n has a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity such that the characteristic of $R$ is $n$,  char$R=n$. Prove that is $n>0$ then $R$ contains a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$$_n$, the additive group of integers modulo n.

Attempt at proof: Consider an isomorphism $\phi: R\rightarrow\ \mathbb{Z}$$_n$ defined as $\phi(x)=[r]$$_n$ where $r$ is the remainder when x divides n. Showing then that $\phi$ is well defined and an isomorphism would conclude the proof.

Is this going in the right direction? Or am I totally off?

Comment: It is literally going in the wrong direction. Try $\mathbb Z_n \to R$. ;)

Comment: Another comment is, what do you mean when $x$ divides $n?$. Your elements in the ring need not be integers, or multiples of 1.

Comment: There's no reason for $R$ to be isomorphic to ${\bf Z}_n$. Consider ${\bf Z}_n^2$.

Answer (score 5):

Think of a map  $\psi:\mathbb{Z}\to R$, where $\psi$ is the map you think it should be =]. Further, what is the kernel of this map?

Comment: If the ring is commutative but without unity and $char R=p$ , a prime number then what will be the mapping? Please help me.

Comment: Here I guess you have taken the map $m \to m.1_R$ for m $\in \mathbb Z$